# Freemarker not entering if/else if values are null

Tags: freemarker

```
<#if myVar = "test">
  A
<#else>
  B
<#/if>
```

If `myVar` is null / not defined, neither A nor B will be output. This is fixed by adding `!` after the variable:

```
<#if myVar! = "test">
  A
<#else>
  B
<#/if>
```

Is this intended? Because if so, it is extremely confusing and I can't imagine any user would expect it to behave this way. It is suggesting that `null = "test"` is somehow neither true nor false. It seems clear that `null = "test"` should always be considered false -- what am I missing?

Note: we have configured Freemarker to replace unknown variables with an empty string:

```
config.setTemplateExceptionHandler((ex, environment, out) ->
{
    if (ex instanceof InvalidReferenceException)
    {
        try
        {
            out.write("");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new TemplateException("Error while handling template exception.", e, environment);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw ex;
    }
});
```

So this would (at least I thought it would) end up being:

```
<#if "" = "test">
  A
<#else>
  B
<#/if>
```

In which case, I'd expect the `else` to be entered for sure -- but it is not.

---

Given this example:

```
<#assign myVar = null/>

<#if myVar == "test">
  A
<#else>
  B
</#if>
```

This throws the following error:

> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ==> null

`myVar` has been evaluated to null **or** missing -- this seems like the source of my confusion; Freemarker does not differentiate between missing and existing-but-null values, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

It's irrelevant if it's `#if`/`#else` or any other directive call, because when an error occurs (any kind of `TemplateException`, not just "missing value"), the whole *statement* is skipped. Not the variable resolution, not even the whole expression, but the whole statement. That's what the Manual and the Javadoc says too, like see: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_errorhandling.html. Therefore, `templateExceptionHandler` setting is not for providing defaults for missing values. It's for handling situations that are genuinely errors. Like, someone did a mistake, something is not operational.

As of why not take the `#else` still. When an error occurs while evaluating the condition, the template engine just can't tell which branch would have been taken if the developers (or whoever) did not make a mistake. Picking either branch of the `if`/`else` is a gamble. (It's not even a 50-50 gamble, as the positive branch tends to be the right one considering the real world meaning of the output, yet, if anything, people expect the template engine to bet on the `else` branch.) So, hoping that you will print some error indicator at least, it rather doesn't pick either branch. But it's really automatic, as the whole `#if`/`#elseif`/`#else` thing is one big statement.

Comment: Note that I'm only handling `InvalidReferenceException` in the `templateExceptionHandler` -- in the case of a missing reference, we return `""`. Other template errors, such as syntax errors, are still thrown. I wouldn't expect it to pick either branch of the `if/else` if there is an actual error -- but a _defined_ variable with a `null` value doesn't seem like it should abandon execution of the statement. I guess it is what it is, though.

Comment: There's no concept of defined variables in the data-model, only of values missing and present. When a `Map` is used instead of a bean, people usually don't put `null`-s into it, just to have the `key` in the `Map` (that would indicate that it's "defined"). Also even with beans, because of subclasses, sometimes you don't have a bean property at all, instead of it being set to `null`. The template author doesn't have a good control over these subtle differences, so the safer compromise is to enforce handling missing values uniformly. At least that's the idea.

Comment: Also note that syntax errors are not handled by the `tempalteExceptionHandler`, since parsing of the whole template happens before execution. So if you have syntax errors, you won't even be able to get the `Template`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<#assign myVar = "test"/>

<#if myVar?? && myVar == "test">
  A
<#else>
  B
</#if>
```

Comment: I know how to fix it, my question is "why, oh why?!".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is intended. When a variable is not defined or null, freemarker will raise an error.

It is explained in the FAQ: [Why is FreeMarker so picky about null-s and missing variables, and what to do with it?](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_picky_about_missing_vars)

This is a design choice from the initial author of the framework. If you are not confortable with this choice, you can use the [Default value operator](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default) (use `myVar!` instead of `myVar`), or use another templating framework.

The custom exception handler you added doesn't replace the expression with an empty String, it replaces the full if/else expression.

Comment: I've shown in my question that I've fixed it by using `myVar!` instead. I'm more asking why it would be this way. I think it is extra confusing in my case because we've configured Freemarker via `setTemplateExceptionHandler` to replace variables which do not exist (`InvalidReferenceException`) with `""` -- so in the end the if is asking `<#if "" = "test">` but it still does not enter the `else`. This seems wrong, doesn't it? I've updated the answer with these details.

Comment: Note that my explanation above might be worthless because in this case, there is a `myVar` variable, just its value is `null`. This is different than if the variable did not exist at all -- in which case I understand/agree that Freemarker should throw an error by default. But here it just silently continues, entering neither portion of the `if/else` -- and that's confusing, and dare I say ... wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<#if condition 1>
-- do here your work for condition 1
<#else>
<#if condition 2>
-- do here your work for condition 2
    <#else>
-- do here your work for else
    </#if>
</#if>
```